# How can we set an alert, in Azure Application Insight, If daily data volume limit is crossed?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to send an alert to application Insight specific user/users(Other then subscription administrator) when daily data volume limit is reached in application Insight.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer: **"Not right now"**

From the team that owns this functionality:

> We will be making this a proper metric that customers can use as a regular metric, then they can do any metric alerts and other scenarios they want to do (including SMS, etc.)
>
> It’s on the backlog to fix this experience correctly.

so right now, no you can't alert on it.

subscription admins *should* be getting an email when you hit the cap, and if you go to the activity log for that application insights resource, you should be able to see an operational event for it:

[image: application insights activity log]